# Marketing cloud Android SDK 7.4.1 crashes when targeting Android 12

Tags: android, salesforce-sdk-android

It appears SDK needs to be updated for Android 12:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: my.app: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a(Unknown Source:16)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a(Unknown Source:74)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.b(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.analytics.a.c.a(Unknown Source:88)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d.c$2.a(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.e.g.run(Unknown Source:17)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No, this is fine @Community

Comment: Thank you Matej.  Looking into it.

Comment: Will you keep us up to date here on any news? API 31 is stable, and we'd also like to target it as soon as possible.

Comment: I have this, and other similar questions followed.  As soon as we release an update that supports Android 12 I will let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MarketingCloud Mobile Push SDK v8.0.0 has been released.  This release includes support for Android 12.

Comment: Thanks! 8.0.0 worked for a while, but now when 8.0.1 is released, you seem to have yanked 8.0.0 from the repositories. Is this intentional? Thought I'd just bring it up in case that was in error.

Comment: 8.0.0 had an issue with notification trampolining on Android 12 devices for builds targeting Android 12.  It was pulled on purpose.  Thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: @BillMote could you please also add the fix to the RN repo? https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Comment: Please open a voice of customer request through your account representative.

Comment: Android 12 support is being added to v7 of the SDK which will work with Cordova and React. Expect a release "soon".