# Cannot compile when targeting Android 12

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, bug

Steps:

- Setup an Android project with `targetSdkVersion 31`
- In the same project, include version v7.4.1 of MarketingCloud: `implementation "com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:7.4.1"`
- Compile the app in Android Studio

Result:

- Compilation fails. Log:

> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps
> targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit
> value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an
> intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.

Looking into the merged application manifest, these activities need to have the exported attributes attributes:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.iam.IamModalActivity"
        android:label="@string/mcsdk_iam_activity_label"
        android:theme="@style/McSdk.Modal" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.iam.IamBannerActivity"
        android:label="@string/mcsdk_iam_activity_label"
        android:theme="@style/McSdk.Banner" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.iam.IamFullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/mcsdk_iam_activity_label"
        android:theme="@style/McSdk.Fullscreen" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.iam.IamFullImageFillActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/mcsdk_iam_activity_label"
        android:theme="@style/McSdk.Fullscreen" />
```

Comment: This is being addressed.  Also see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/355238/marketing-cloud-android-sdk-7-4-1-crashes-when-targeting-android-12

Comment: @BillMote Any ETA for the new version? This is currently blocking our release process.

Comment: With the recent release of Android 12 Beta 4, the required changes are being peer-reviewed, will go through testing, UA, and then be released.  I am not in a position to promise external deliveries, but I can tell you "soon."

Answer (score 0):

MarketingCloud Mobile Push SDK v8.0.0 has been released.  This release includes support for Android 12.